# Calendar events are showing 8 mins late in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: calendar, 21.04

Notification Center events

[image: Notification Center events]

Calendar App events

[image: Calendar App events]

I have installed Ubuntu 21.04 in my pc. All the events in the notification center are appearing 8 mins late. However they are showing the correct time in the pre-installed Calendar app. How can I resolve this?

(The events are of my gmail account).

**UPD:**

Here are the outputs of the following commands: `timedatectl status` and `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`

[image: timedatectl status]

[image: systemctl status systemd-timesyncd]

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add the outputs of the following commands: `timedatectl status` and `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have added the required outputs. can you check again please?

Comment: I was suspecting that your system clock was not synchronized. But it seems ok. I have no further ideas unfortunately. ☹️ (BTW, please never paste screenshots, while you can just copy and paste the relevant text from your terminal.)